# JavaScript: Get variable name in method defined in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, variable-names

How can I get the variable name in a method, which I defined in the prototype of String()?

```
String.prototype.foobar = function() {alert(/*something here...*/);};
var s="I'm just a stupid string!";
s.foobar();
```

Should return an alert which contains "s"...

How can I manage this?

regards.

**Edit:**

You can download the result of this topic here: https://github.com/ninov/onChange

Answer (score 1):

*"I want to make kind of custom event, which checks if the string changend"*

That's impossible. Strings are immutable.

And if you want the function to alert the actual variable name, that's impossible too. If you have a String object, there can be several variables referencing the same object. How would it know which name to use?

You should define an object that does what you want. Preferably with setters and getters.

To ensure that you get notified of a change to the variable referencing the string, you could do this:

```
var str_obj = (function() {

    var s = "my string";

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return s;
        },
        setString: function( new_s ) {
            s = new_s;
            alert("s changed!");
        }
    };
})();

alert( str_obj.getString() ); // alerts "my string"

str_obj.setString( "new string" ); // alerts "s changed!"

alert( str_obj.getString() ); // alerts "new string"
```

Comment: Yes, this is a *much* better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has string primitives (which are not true javascript objects) and string objects which have methods.  I assume the string primitives are more efficient and a statically declared string like you have will default to being a primitive.  In most cases, Javascript will automatically convert a primitive to an object when needed.  When I run your code in Chrome, it does so and I do get an alert.

If you want to make sure it's an object, you can declare it like this:

```
String.prototype.foobar = function() {alert("fun");};
var s = new String("I'm just a stupid string!");
s.foobar();
```

For more info on this topic see the section "Distinction between string primitives and String objects" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

If what you're trying to do is to get the variable name from the foobar() method, then that is not something that Javascript supports in any standard way.

If neither of these are what you're actually asking, please clarify your question.

Comment: Let us assume it is a String object... How can I do this? (__s = new String();__)

Comment: @ninov - I don't understand your question.  `var s = new String("aaa");` works just fine.  What else are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well, this actually works.</strike>

If you change that snippet to:

```
String.prototype.foobar = function() {alert(this);};
```

then `s.foobar();` will alert `"I'm just a stupid string!"`

If that does not work for you, please tell on which engine you're testing.

I'm afraid there is no way to get the original variable name.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for. It's about the variable name, not value

Comment: Although alerting may work fine with `this`, it might be worth noting that `this` is a `String` object, not a primitive string.

Comment: @pimvdb but how can I get the name of the String Object?

Comment: If you mean literally `"s"` then I guess you're out of luck since the variable name is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. And it shouldn't have to be.

If you really want to know this meta-data, you should consider to use an object:

```
var obj = {
   s: "I'm just a stupid string!"
};

for(var x in obj){
  alert(x + '=' + obj[x]); // logs: s=I'm just a stupid string!
}
```

But why would you want to know the variable name programmatically?

Comment: I want to make  kind of custom event, which checks if the string changend: s.onchange(function(){alert("s changed!");}); and the onchange method should start an interval which checks if the variable s changed every 10ms....

Comment: @ninov: That is a very questionable way of achieving this. I would strongly suggest you use a more specific data structure for doing this. If you want to mediate or detect changes to an object, encapsulate the data and provide accessor methods to retrieve or change the value (e.g. `setValue() { /* ... */ }`). With that approach, you do not have to come up with any hacks to detect changes -- simply fire some event function whenever `setValue()` is called.